# tcolorbox : attach boxed title has no effect

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex}, % NO EFFECT !!!
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

the output pdf:

[image]

I don't know the reason why the title is above

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can't reproduce your image with your code. The shifting works well and hello world is placed on the line.

Comment: You should not use `ex` length units here. Try `mm` or `pt` instead

Comment: The examples in the `tcolorbox` manual never use `ex` units, only `mm`, `cm` or `pt` are applied. The `ex` specification is disregarded either by design or it is a bug

Comment: thank you, now it works fine but why it does not work using ex, I inform you that this problem appeared after installing texlive 2017, I do not know that texlive 2017 is the cause. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Since ex is font dependent, it might not make any sense in tikz (which is what tcolorbox uses). In some of its constructions tikz does something strange to the current font (making it nullfont?) and thus things like ex and em might simply not be defined at the to imellem of use.

Comment: @daleif: That's what I thought or suspected too

Comment: The "to imellem" should have been "time"

Comment: @daleif Correct. From manual chapter 12.2:  "Next, the contents of the environment is processed and the graphic commands therein are put into a box. Non-graphic text is suppressed as well as possible, but non-pgf commands inside a `{tikzpicture}` environment should not produce any “output” since this may totally scramble the positioning system
of the backend drivers. The suppressing of normal text, by the way, is done by temporarily switching the font to `\nullfont`. You can, however, “escape back” to normal TeX typesetting. This happens, for example, when you specify a node."

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Using a CW answer here as a combinations of the comments by daleif, Torbjørn T and myself.

None of the examples in the `tcolorbox` manual uses the `ex` dimension, only `cm`, `pt` or `mm` are used.

`attach boxed title to top left` uses `TikZ` in the background, this in turn uses the `\nullfont` in order to suppress (see the [tcolorbox : attach boxed title has no effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390262/tcolorbox-attach-boxed-title-has-no-effect/416997#comment969016_390262) comment), as such `ex` has no effect as a dimension specification.

Thanks to daleif and Torbjørn T. for their useful comments -- those posts were incorporated here in short.

Back to the code itself -- shifting could be done with some reasonable values, such as `\tcboxedtitleheight/2`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    frame hidden,
  },
  title=#2,
  #1
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]